# iOS, Determine network access type

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, core-telephony

I am trying to get the network type on an iPhone. I am using the following procedure:

```
(NSNumber *) dataNetworkTypeFromStatusBar {

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"]    subviews];
    NSNumber *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

    for (id subview in subviews) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }
    return [dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"dataNetworkType"];
}
```

I can succesfully get the network type while the app is in the foreground, but the network type is not updated when the app is in the background. Can anyone please tell me how I could get the procedure to update the information in the background as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in iOS 7.0+ we have `CoreTelephony` framework which can provide us the required details about network type.

Here is a sample.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
        NSString *currentRadio = telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology;
        if ([currentRadio isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
            // LTE

        } else if([currentRadio isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge]) {
            // EDGE

        } else if([currentRadio isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA]){
            // 3G

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is very bad I'm afraid, you should use the Reachability code from Apple, you can use it to find out if there is a network and what kind (3G, WiFi etc...)

Check out the code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html